# AspectJ defining Pointcut on annotation with matching argument value

Tags: aop, aspectj

I have a process defined using `Process`[annotation](https://github.com/rajsenthil/aspectj/blob/master/src/main/java/com/spring/aspect/interfaces/annotation/Process.java). This annotation has the property called `name`. Process contains tasks in it. The tasks are defined with another [annotation](https://github.com/rajsenthil/aspectj/blob/master/src/main/java/com/spring/aspect/interfaces/annotation/Task.java) called `Task`. This annotation has property `processName`. 
I have a [generic process](https://github.com/rajsenthil/aspectj/blob/master/src/main/java/com/spring/aspect/interfaces/process/GenericProcess.java) with `name` as **Generic**. The tasks for this process are [Task1](https://github.com/rajsenthil/aspectj/blob/master/src/main/java/com/spring/aspect/interfaces/task/Task1.java), [Task2](https://github.com/rajsenthil/aspectj/blob/master/src/main/java/com/spring/aspect/interfaces/task/Task2.java) and [Task3](https://github.com/rajsenthil/aspectj/blob/master/src/main/java/com/spring/aspect/interfaces/task/Task3.java) , all three with `processName` as **Generic**. 
Can I use the aspectj such that, all the tasks with same `processName` are grouped under the '''Process'''? Also when the [GenericProcess.execute](https://github.com/rajsenthil/aspectj/blob/master/src/main/java/com/spring/aspect/interfaces/process/GenericProcessImpl.java#L12) is invoked, the tasks in it are all needs to get triggered as well.
The code that I am trying is currently in [github](https://github.com/rajsenthil/aspectj).
Thanks for the help.

Comment: I think by the nature of grouping, the weaving supposed to happen at compile time.

Comment: I am not sure how feasible with Aspectj for grouping the tasks under a process and then intercept them for the task execution.

Comment: a) What do you mean by "tasks are grouped"? b) In your question don do not even mention that `Task1` etc. are also aspects, but your GitHub repo shows it (thanks for sharing). As explained already in detail in [my answer to your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57899444/1082681), in Spring AOP you cannot intercept one aspect from another one. This is also [documented](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop-at-aspectj) under " 
Advising aspects with other aspects?". Why didn't you just follow my advice to use AspectJ with LTW instead?

Comment: a) For Grouping tasks, I am trying to have a Process defined with one or more tasks in it. As in this [GenericProcess](https://github.com/rajsenthil/aspectj/blob/master/src/main/java/com/spring/aspect/interfaces/process/GenericProcess.java), I used the process name as **Generic**. This process contains [Task1](https://github.com/rajsenthil/aspectj/blob/master/src/main/java/com/spring/aspect/interfaces/task/Task1.java) and other tasks with the process name as **Generic**. I want to group them.

Comment: b) I am using the AspectJ as you have provided before. Sorry for the confusion.
I am looking for aspect where when Process **Generic** is invoked its method [execute](https://github.com/rajsenthil/aspectj/blob/master/src/main/java/com/spring/aspect/interfaces/process/GenericProcessImpl.java#L12), then its tasks like [Task1](https://github.com/rajsenthil/aspectj/blob/master/src/main/java/com/spring/aspect/interfaces/task/Task1.java#L12) having process name **Generic** to be invoked by aspectj pointcut.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you should have mentioned that your application does not even run, it exits with an error. In general, it is pretty much a mess. Maybe you should have tested it and looked into the logs before publishing it on GitHub. You also should have posted log output showing the errors instead of just basically saying "it does not work". I had to fix many things:

- First I removed (or rather renamed) *application.yml* and *logback.xml* because I neither  have your H2 database and your project does not create one, nor did I see any log output on the console. Of course for you those settings might work, for me they do not.
- Then in your `Application` there is `Process process = context.getBean(Process.class);` which makes no sense because `Process` is not a bean class but an annotation. You took my code from the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57899444/1082681), changed many things and then nothing fit together anymore. Now your application looks like this:

```java
package com.spring.aspect.interfaces;

import com.spring.aspect.interfaces.process.GenericProcess;
import org.modelmapper.ModelMapper;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
  private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Application.class);

  @Bean
  public ModelMapper modelMapper() {
    return new ModelMapper();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    GenericProcess process = context.getBean(GenericProcess.class);
    log.info("Generic process = {}", process);
    process.execute();
  }
}
```

- In your task aspects `Task{1,2,3}` the pointcut `execution(public com.spring.aspect.interfaces.entity.Job com.spring.aspect.interfaces.process.GenericProcessImpl.process(..)) && args(context)` is invalid because neither is there a `GenericProcessImpl.process(..)` method nor does it have a `Context` argument. what you have instead is a `void execute()` method with no arguments.
- Besides, that method is just from the implemented `GenericProcess` interface, i.e. we could use that interface instead of a specific implementation as a pointcut.
- I also don't see the need to use an expensive `@Around` advice if you just want to log something, `@Before` would be sufficient. So how about this?

```java
package com.spring.aspect.interfaces.task;

import com.spring.aspect.interfaces.annotation.Provided;
import com.spring.aspect.interfaces.annotation.Required;
import com.spring.aspect.interfaces.annotation.Task;
import org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

@Task(name = "Task1", processName = "Generic")
@Required(values = { "param1" })
@Provided(values = { "param2" })
@Aspect
public class Task1 {
  Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Task1.class.getName());

  @Before("execution(public void com.spring.aspect.interfaces.process.GenericProcess+.execute())")
  public void task(JoinPoint thisJoinPoint) {
    logger.info("{}", thisJoinPoint);
  }
}
```

```java
package com.spring.aspect.interfaces.task;

import com.spring.aspect.interfaces.annotation.Provided;
import com.spring.aspect.interfaces.annotation.Required;
import com.spring.aspect.interfaces.annotation.Task;
import org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

@Task(name = "Task2", processName = "Generic")
@Required(values = { "param2" })
@Provided(values = { "param3" })
@Aspect
public class Task2 {
  Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Task2.class.getName());

  @Before("execution(public void com.spring.aspect.interfaces.process.GenericProcess+.execute())")
  public void task(JoinPoint thisJoinPoint) {
    logger.info("{}", thisJoinPoint);
  }
}
```

```java
package com.spring.aspect.interfaces.task;

import com.spring.aspect.interfaces.annotation.Required;
import com.spring.aspect.interfaces.annotation.Task;
import org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

@Task(name = "Task3", processName = "Generic")
@Required(values = { "param1", "param2" })
@Aspect
public class Task3 {
  Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Task3.class.getName());

  @Before("execution(public void com.spring.aspect.interfaces.process.GenericProcess+.execute())")
  public void task(JoinPoint thisJoinPoint) {
    logger.info("{}", thisJoinPoint);
  }
}
```

- Last but not least, in `TaskAspect` you use `@annotation(com.spring.aspect.interfaces.annotation.Task)` which would match methods with a `@Task` annotation. But you have classes with that annotation, so you ought to use `@within(com.spring.aspect.interfaces.annotation.Task)` instead.
- Even easier than trying to bind the `Task` annotation to an argument via `target(task)` would be to just use `@within(task)` instead, getting you both the annotation matching and the parameter binding at once.
- Remember we changed the task pointcuts from `@Around` to `@Before` above? For `@Before` AspectJ does not generate methods but weaves the code directly into the target classes. You also cannot rely on it to do that for `@Around` advices, so my answer to your previous question was working but a bit unclean. There is a special pointcut designator `adviceexecution()`, though. Its purpose is to intercept executing advices from other aspects (or even from the same one). This is cleaner and more generic. In this case it is even the only thing that works.
- Finally, you are using `args(proceedingJoinPoint)`, I have no idea why. Did you try to bind the pointcut from the intercepted `Task{1,2,3}` advices to the `TaskAspect` advice? It would not work that way because AspectJ binds the executing advice's joinpoint to an existing first parameter of type `JoinPoint` or `ProceedingJoinPoint`. Maybe it would work binding it to a second joinpoint parameter. Anyway, we don't need it, so let us just remove it. This is really contrived, wow.
- One more thing, why are you using `task.getClass().getName()` instead of your newly introduced `@Task` annotation properties in order to log information?

```java
package com.spring.aspect.interfaces.aspect;

import com.spring.aspect.interfaces.annotation.Task;
import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

@Aspect
public class TaskAspect {
  static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TaskAspect.class.getName());

  @Around("@within(task) && adviceexecution()")
  public Object groupTasks(ProceedingJoinPoint proceedingJoinPoint, Task task) throws Throwable {
    logger.info("Generalizing the task aspects");
    logger.info("  {}", proceedingJoinPoint);
    logger.info("  Task = {}", task.name());
    logger.info("  Process = {}", task.processName());
    return proceedingJoinPoint.proceed();
  }
}
```

Now finally the application and aspects are working again, at least if you start the application with the `-javaagent:"/path/to/aspectjweaver.jar"` parameter. Now you should see log output like this (removing AspectJ weaver output and some leading logger columns):

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.1.3.RELEASE)

(...)
o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
c.spring.aspect.interfaces.Application   : Started Application in 2.948 seconds (JVM running for 4.934)
c.spring.aspect.interfaces.Application   : Generic process = com.spring.aspect.interfaces.process.GenericProcessImpl@25d0cb3a
c.s.aspect.interfaces.aspect.TaskAspect  : Generalizing the task aspects
c.s.aspect.interfaces.aspect.TaskAspect  :   adviceexecution(void com.spring.aspect.interfaces.task.Task3.task(JoinPoint))
c.s.aspect.interfaces.aspect.TaskAspect  :   Task = Task3
c.s.aspect.interfaces.aspect.TaskAspect  :   Process = Generic
com.spring.aspect.interfaces.task.Task3  : execution(void com.spring.aspect.interfaces.process.GenericProcessImpl.execute())
c.s.aspect.interfaces.aspect.TaskAspect  : Generalizing the task aspects
c.s.aspect.interfaces.aspect.TaskAspect  :   adviceexecution(void com.spring.aspect.interfaces.task.Task1.task(JoinPoint))
c.s.aspect.interfaces.aspect.TaskAspect  :   Task = Task1
c.s.aspect.interfaces.aspect.TaskAspect  :   Process = Generic
com.spring.aspect.interfaces.task.Task1  : execution(void com.spring.aspect.interfaces.process.GenericProcessImpl.execute())
c.s.aspect.interfaces.aspect.TaskAspect  : Generalizing the task aspects
c.s.aspect.interfaces.aspect.TaskAspect  :   adviceexecution(void com.spring.aspect.interfaces.task.Task2.task(JoinPoint))
c.s.aspect.interfaces.aspect.TaskAspect  :   Task = Task2
c.s.aspect.interfaces.aspect.TaskAspect  :   Process = Generic
com.spring.aspect.interfaces.task.Task2  : execution(void com.spring.aspect.interfaces.process.GenericProcessImpl.execute())
c.s.a.i.process.GenericProcessImpl       : Generic Process execution is invoked
```

---

**Update:**

- I have slightly modified `TaskAspect` with regard to log output.
- I also made the logger package-scoped so I can inject a mock from a test.
- Subsequently I have refactored your `ProcessTest` into my `TaskAspectTest` and moved it to the same package as `TaskAspect`. It looks as follows:

```java
package com.spring.aspect.interfaces.aspect;

import com.spring.aspect.interfaces.process.GenericProcess;
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;

import static org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.any;
import static org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.anyString;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.times;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.verify;

/**
 * Attention: Run this test with JVM parameter -javaagent:/path/to/aspectjweaver.jar
 */
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class TaskAspectTest {
  @Autowired
  private GenericProcess genericProcess;

  @Mock
  private Logger mockLogger;
  private Logger originalLogger;

  @Before
  public void setup() {
    originalLogger = TaskAspect.logger;
    TaskAspect.logger = mockLogger;
  }

  @After
  public void cleanup() {
    TaskAspect.logger = originalLogger;
  }

  /**
   * The way TaskAspect is currently implemented, its only side effect is logging output,
   * so the only way we can check if the aspect is executed as expected is to inject a
   * mock logger and verify if it was called as often as expected, i.e. once for each
   * Task1, Task2, Task3, with 1+3 log lines per execution.
   */
  @Test
  public void testAspectExecution() {
    genericProcess.execute();
    verify(mockLogger, times(3)).info(anyString());
    verify(mockLogger, times(9)).info(anyString(), any(Object.class));
  }
}
```

---

**Update 2:**

- I also added AspectJ LTW configuration to your Maven build now, see [these commits in my fork](https://github.com/kriegaex/SO_AJ_SpringAspectJLTW_58067810/compare/3859141...kriegaex:126b9f6).
- I created a [pull request (PR)](https://github.com/rajsenthil/aspectj/pull/1) for you which you can just accept in order to get all my changes into your project without copy & paste.

Comment: I did some refactoring pulling out code from the main repo. My bad, I was not aware that code breaks. Thanks again, There was a great explanation and I need to sometime to go through it.

Comment: **Update:** I added an integration test for `TaskAspect`, maybe you want to take a look. Please note that if you want to run the application or the test successfully, you need to put the AspectJ weaver on the JVM command line as a Java agent. You need to do this both in your Maven Surefire settings and in your IDE run/test configurations. Now there is no more excuse not to notice if that aspect breaks. You should have tested manually before pushing this stuff to GitHub, but it is even better to automate your tests. Your own test did not verify anything at all, it was just a dummy.

Comment: **Update 2:** I also added AspectJ LTW configuration to your Maven build now and created a pull request (PR) for you which you can just accept in order to get all my changes into your project without copy & paste.